# Is 'to smoke' a complement or adjunct in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, complements, adjuncts, verb-patterns

I hope you are all well.

He stopped to smoke.

Is to smoke a complement of stop or is it an infinitive-of-purpose adjunct?

Comment: _To smoke_ is a purpose infinitive. _Stop_, unlike _start_, can take only gerund complements (_He stopped smoking, he started smoking, he started to smoke_), so any infinitive following it has to be an adjunct.

Comment: Yo! Do I detect a Devonian twang? Gonna give you an answer in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> *To smoke* is a purpose infinitive. *Stop*, unlike *start*, can take only gerund complements (*He stopped smoking, he started smoking, he started to smoke*), so any infinitive following it has to be an adjunct.

Comment: 'Perhaps 'He stopped to tie his shoelace'  affords fewer garden-path opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

As you will tell from my answers, I like to focus on readability. At the satisfaction of my readers. Always imagining that they could give me a star rating based on the enjoyment of my book or sentence.

So for me, I think you need to clarify for the reader what you're trying to say.

Are you just missing a comma?
as in, "he stopped, to smoke." *an infinitive-of-purpose adjunct?*

Comment: I'd say << He stopped, to smoke >> is less natural than << He stopped to smoke >> (and far less idiomatic than << He stopped for a cigarette >> or << He stopped for a smoke >> ).  None of the examples showing purpose-infinitives at [Perfect English-grammar.com](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/infinitives-of-purpose.html#:~:text=Infinitives%20of%20Purpose&text=We%20can%20use%20to%20%2B%20infinitive,is%20why%20I%20did%20it), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infinitive_of_purpose) or by Nordquist at ThoughtCo use the comma before the to-infinitival.

Answer (score -1):

IMO, "to smoke" should be a direct object of "stopped" which is derived from a noun clause "that he will/would smoke".

Comment: So you are saying that ***to smoke was stopped by him***?! How can that possibly make any sense, grammatically or otherwise? That is what saying it's the direct object necessarily leads to, but its ungrammatically disproves your premise.

Comment: my opinion may be a bit weird.

"to smoke" there should be understood as "he will/would smoke" since any verb, whether finite or non-finite, require a subject to do it.

so "to smoke" in the subject position should be read as "something (I will/would smoke) was stopped by him. 

is this structure (something was stopped by him) grammatically correct?